# Check mobile token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can you tell me if there is a possibility to verify mobile tokens?

We have a mobile application, when logging into the server, the user receives a token. The token + user_id is written to the database The token is needed to send push messages through firebase cloud messaging.

That is the question: when installing the application again or updating, the user receives a new token, how to remove an old token? Perhaps there is a check in Firebase? The uniqueness by user_id is not suitable since it should be possible to install on different devices.
Do we send 3-4 tokens at a time to firebase and cannot check a specific token for sending a message? Or can we?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group Notifications send notifications to multiple devices with same user.

Use cloud function to create/update a device group with FCM token when it updates.
[More info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)

When device group updated, you can send notification to that perticular group using cloud finction and it will be received by all devices. You don't need to replace or maintain expired tokens that way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to **store the token in the device's local storage**.

If the token was refresh or an update happened, you will get a new token. Then, you check if there's another token saved or not. If saved, send both to server and do a replacement. Else, consider it a new user.